# C GSL Bessel function example

Tags: c, gsl

I tried the following code:

```
# include <stdio.h> 
# include <gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h> 
int main (void)
{
double x = 5.0; 
double y = gsl_sf_bessel_j0 (x); 
printf ("JO(%g) =  %.18e\n", x , y);
return(0);
}
```

the result I get is:

```
JO(5) =  -1.917848549326277019e-01
```

The result given in the GSL manual is

```
-1.775967713143382920e-01
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: more info, I am using a Mac with "el capitan' and this is how i compile: clang -L/opt/local/lib -lgsl main.o -o bessel

Comment: I can reproduce your results. Comparing with two more implementations of the J0 function, I tend to conclude that there is a bug in GSL.

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed looks like a bug to me. I seems that it has not been fixed yet according to the [changelist](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gsl.git/tree/NEWS). However, there are two possible reasons:

- A typo in the documentation. Instead of gsl_sf_bessel_j0 you should use gsl_sf_bessel_J0 (very strange naming). That gives you `JO(5) =  -1.775967713143382642e-01` which is close enough to the desired answer (I'm not sure about the precision though).
- The documentation is correct, we need to fix the function itself.

Anyway, since it's not been reported I've submitted a bug report. I do plan to update this answer as soon as I get any information related to this problem.